# Getting user data from session

Tags: php, mysql, session

I made a login system and it works but I also have the user's session in the page after login.

How can I get user data from my database by referencing the user's session, and how can I update it when the user put what they going to change

```
<?php   
session_start();                        
$query=mysql_query("SELECT username, email, password FROM user WHERE  username = $_SESSION['username']");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {

 echo .row['username'];
 echo .row['email'];
 echo .row ['password'];

 ?>
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking, what is the user going to change in the database and where are you updating data?

Comment: sorry for my bad english

Comment: the user want to change email username and password, so when he login,he can type his name as login user in the index page, after that he can fill in the form and change the data then click update for updating his information.

Answer (score 0):

In new codes you should be using mysqli if your PHP version is high enough (if not... update...)

But here you go:

```
<?php   
session_start();                        
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE  username = {$_SESSION['username']}");
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

 echo $row['username'];
 echo $row['email'];
 echo $row ['password'];

 ?>
```

Oh and the update:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET username={$_POST['username']}, email={$_POST['email']}, password={$_POST['password']} WHERE username={$_SESSION['username']}");
?>
```

And you should make a form for that..

Comment: sir i get this eror when i try to put the code inside it

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\esop\edituser.php on line 89

Comment: note- when using array vars with quoted keys inside double quotes, they need to be wrapped in curly brackets `{$_SESSION['username']}`. You could also remove the quotes `$_SESSION[username]`. see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: sir i get this eror from the code u give, = 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\esop\edituser.php on line 89

Comment: @Sean Indeed, updated my code. Try again with my new code.

Comment: yeah but i got eror from that, and i dont know what is the eror about

Comment: Did you use the code I updated? And what code do you have on line 89?

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Cris is almost perfect and well explained. But it is missing the quotes for the string in the statement.

As the col username will most likely be a varchar of any length.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE  username = '{$_SESSION['username']}'");
```